# Database Transactions in Java on Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to translate some of the code of Objective C in Java...

```
[_db beginTransaction];

    Date now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    boolean result = [_db executeUpdate:updateQuery, [self stringToDB:account.userId],
                   [self integerToDB:account.accountId],
                   [self integerToDB:account.accountType],
                   [self stringToDB:account.accountName],
                ];

    [_db commit];
    return true;
```

Can anyone tell me how can i implement `BeginTransaction and Commit` in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this 'Android', the Android SDK has a SQLiteDatabase class that's typically wrapped by a helper class (if you follow the guides/tuts/etc. out there).

SQLiteDatabase has `beginTransaction()` and `endTransaction()` that let you run... erm, database transactions.  `endTransaction()` is sort of like a commit but with caveats.  Refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29) for more info.

Comment: That is what i am looking for :) Reading the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in my framework by creating a reusable [TxHandle](https://github.com/gorefest/baracus-framework/blob/master/src/main/java/net/mantucon/baracus/dao/BaseDao.java) supporting db-styled begin, commit and rollback functionality. Sometimes I want to do mass data processing with transaction safety so I create a transaction handle and pass it to the DAO in order to process a bunch of rows and therefore it hides this - to me a little bit confusing - API.

But honestly, the default use case is to have single row commits by default; multi-row updates in a ORM universe is the exception, so you might want to take a look the [Dao-Implementation Tutorial](http://baracusframework.blogspot.de/2013/10/baracus-from-scratch-part-5-advanced.html) in order to avoid fiddling with rows.

Feel free to verbatim any code fragment.